# How are regular and composite indexes implemented in RDBs?

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, tree, implementation

In databases like MySQL or Oracle, how are indexes implemented? I think regular indexes are stored as B-trees, but couldn't find anything about composite indexes that index on multiple columns. I'm looking for the names of the data structures used so I can research them.

More generally, where can I find more such information about database implementation details? I'm going to be taking a course on that much later in university, but I'm curious right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Composite indexes also use B-Trees, they just concatenate the indexed columns to determine the key. As a side node, Oracle also knows other index types, i.e. bitmap indexes. But that doesn't depend on the number of columns indexed.

Answer (score 4):

B-trees.  Every index is stored as a B-tree -- even composite ones.

If you're looking to do more research on how indexes are organized, look into B+ trees and B* trees.  For SQL Server, [Kalen Delaney's Inside SQL Server: The Storage Engine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621055) is an excellent book about the nuts and bolts of SQL Server, including its index organization.  So you should definitely check that out.

A commenter points out that Oracle can use bitmap indexes, which are structured very differently than B-trees, but those are rarely used for traditional relational databases -- they're used more often for OLAP type applications and in cases where you need fast access on a nonselective group of data.

EDIT: SQL Server, for example, now uses [Columnstore Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx).  If you do any work with large BI type workloads, it's definitely worth looking at these, as they store your data in an entirely different way than a B-Tree.

SQL Server also uses a different mechanism now for [memory optimized tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133165.aspx) as well, and is something that's very useful for OLTP type queries.

Comment: Except for ones that aren't - like bitmap indexes in Oracle.

Comment: I really did not understand why this answer got a downvote. The provided book reference was pretty helpful and it generally made the same point as the accepted answer.